# How to compare the similarity of two waveforms in c#?

Tags: c#, audio, compare, waveform

I am trying to compare the similarity of two waveforms based on the visual aspect of the waveform and not how they sound.
How would I be able to do this in c#?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show the code.

Comment: This is way beyond what could be reasonably answered on a Q&A site such as stackoverflow

Comment: What do you consider "similar"? Frequency? Amplitude? Complexity? Envelope?

Answer (score 0):

If the data of the waveforms are in a format such that the value at time = 0 can be indexed as waveform[0] and the next "frame" of the wave can be indexed as waveform[1] and the max value for a "frame" of a wave is 1 and the min value for a "frame" of a wave is -1, (and the two waves are the same length in units of "frames"), then I *think* this should work: (untested)

```
//WaveForm 1 is w1 and WaveForm 2 is w2.
Stack<float> temp = new Stack<float>();
for(int i = 0; i < w1.Length; i++)
{
    //differenceFactor is the variable that decides what difference means.
    //at a value of 1, then a two waves with indexes -0.5 and 0.5 will be "100%" 
    //different. At a value of 0.5f then two waves with indexes -0.5 and 0.5 will be 
    //"50%" different. According to what I see, if differenceFactor > 1f then wave 
    //indexes greater than 1 unit apart are more than "100%" different, so probably don't 
    //do that.
    float difference = Math.Abs(w1[i] - w2[i]);
    temp.Push(((difference < differenceFactor) ? difference : differenceFactor) * 0.5f);
}
return temp.Average();
```